# How to use view as a replacement for tr tag

Tags: ember.js

regarding the different posts I read I would have expected that the following code should work:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each NewApp.router.gridController.tableContent}}
        {{#view NewApp.TableRow rowBinding="this"}}
            <td style="width: 100px">{{row.item_no}}</td>
            <td align="right" style="width: 100px">{{row.price}}</td>
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

But I get only empty table rows. If I use tr everything works as expected.

The TableRow is defined as:

```
NewApp.TableRow = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "tr",

  row: null,

  willInsertElement: function() {
    console.dir(this.get("row"));
  }

});
```

BTW: console.dir shows the correct data.

Regards
  Roger

Comment: How are you initializing the controller and view in your `Route`? can you show some of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.CollectionView&src=false, it can simplify your code.

For your example, use {{view.row.XXX}} in the template, it should do the job

Comment: @rogergl It's due to the fact that views preserve context of their parent view. So to access the context of the current view, you have to explicitly prefix the properties with "view"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But all the examples I found worked without the view prefix.  Maybe some recent API change ?

Comment: @rogergl Yep, but I'm not sure this behavior will be definitive. I don't know what is the plan of the ember team concerning it.